# can we use java socketchannel to communicate with c based TCP server

Tags: java, android, socketchannel

can we use socketchannel to communicate with c++ based TCP server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.. Just pass the correct IP and port number in the socket constructor.

Comment: @ChiragRaval Why? It's not only an answer, it's a correct answer.

Comment: @ChiragRaval and why you think so ? This is the most direct answer to a simple direct question. I would have added code (after all the example code is just a google search away or just a search in my eclipse) but I didn't add that. Since that was not asked in the question. Now if the OP wants the code he/she can ask for that in a comment to this answer or by an edit of the question.

Comment: This is like to ask "can a java program read a file written by a c++ program".